# Jest test fails on a jQuery custom widget

Tags: jquery-ui, testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test my React component with Jest. My test fails  (actually it doesn't even run) because I use a custom jQuery UI widget for the form in the component. I don't need to test that widget with Jest, so I was wondering if there is a way to instruct Jest to skip completely whatever is related to that jQuery widget.

Otherwise if is there a way to make my test run at least!

Thank you in advance for your time.

This is the error that Jest return

● Runtime Error
TypeError: $.widget is not a function